# does this relation associated with a poset have a name?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Given a partial order $P$ on a set $S$ does the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ in $S\times S\setminus P$ such that $P\cup\{(x,y)\}$ is a partial order have a name? (If so then it would apply to all sorts of orders not just partial orders.)

The answer was "no" in this crosspost: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/155928/relation-based-on-a-given-partial-order-does-it-have-a-name

If MathOverflow concurs, then it must not have a name yet.  (I named it the *envelope* of $P.)$

============== edit added 2 June 2023=================

[Some parrot-like ChatGPT answers were added then removed when I learned that ChatGPT content is banned.]

Comment: "Envelope" is a strange name for a set that does not contain the original set.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky my so-called (for now, until someone suggests a better name) *envelope* is equivalent to a certain collection of partial orders, each of which not only contains the original partial order, but does so in a maximally snug fashion.

Comment: The biggest problem with *envelope* is that it's used for other things in other areas.  Was hoping there would already be a name for this.  That's looking very unlikely given the comment by @JoelDavidHamkins, which by the way might serve as a better foundation for the name than my definition in the question.

Comment: I think the relation deserves to be represented by more than just a symbol.

Comment: I think that ChatGPT's answers to this question are irrelevant, at least as part of the question.  (I would say that, if you really want to share them, then you can share them as an answer … but ChatGPT-generated answers are [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), so don't do that.  In fact the [linked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) says that ChatGPT-generated *content* is banned, period.)

Comment: This is now https://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001902/

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You are right. I retract my comment (and have deleted).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე assuming $x$ and $y$ are incomparable, the sense in which $x$ is minimal and $y$ maximal is that no point incomparable to $y$ is strictly less than $x$ (thus $x$ is minimal among such points) and no point incomparable to $x$ is strictly greater than $y$.

Comment: @mathematrucker In this sense, yes, even smallest, resp. greatest, not just minimal, resp. maximal. In other words, necessary and sufficient conditions are ${\downarrow}(x)\setminus{\downarrow}(y)=\{x\}$ and ${\uparrow}(y)\setminus{\uparrow}(x)=\{y\}$, right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე yes this dual pair of equations elegantly captures incomparability and optimality in one fell swoop...very nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that there is no established name for this concept, but if you are looking for a suggestion, **"potential covers"** might be a reasonable name, since these are precisely the pairs $(x,y)$ which are not in the partial order $P$ but would be a cover in $P\cup \{(x,y)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this good name for the pairs.  It arises naturally and shows up in some recent papers.  I changed "envelope" to the more available, more descriptive  "extender" and will include "potential cover" in the definition.